# Methods for comparing structure of multiple covariance matrices

Tags: r, covariance-matrix

I am familiar with methods to compare the global structure of multiple covariance matrices (eg. Calsbeek, B. and C. J. Goodnight (2009). “Empirical comparison of G matrix test statistics: finding biologically relevant change.” Evolution 63: 2627-2635.; Goodnight, C. J. and J. M. Schwartz (1997). “A bootstrap comparison of genetic covariance matrices.” Biometrics 53: 1026-1039.) which implement bootstrap comparisons to assess whether two covariance matrices are significantly different from each other.

I want to go a step further and evaluate what differences in covariance matrix modularity lead to these differences.

```
library(ComplexHeatmap)
set.seed(123)
data <- matrix(abs(rnorm(49)),nrow=7)
```

Given a covariance matrix `a` that represents the consensus or baseline of multiple biological samples:

```
a <- cor(data)
colnames(a) <- rownames(a) <- LETTERS[1:nrow(a)]
hc = hclust(dist(a, method="euclidean"), method = "complete")
hm_a <- Heatmap(a, cluster_rows = hc, cluster_columns = hc, name = "a")
draw(hm_a)
```

[image]

We may say that variables B,C,G and variables E,F represent correlated modules. This could be evaluated by assembling multiple random modules and testing if module B,C,G is more correlated than equally sized random modules.

Imagine the covariance matrix for sample `b` has a slightly different structure.

```
col_order <- row_order <- column_order(hm_a)
b <- a
b["D","E"] <- b["D","F"] <- b["E","D"] <- b["F","D"] <- 1
Heatmap(b, row_order = col_order, column_order = col_order, name = "b")
```

[image]

Here it may be reasonable to conclude that variable D is now a member of a module with E,F.

In sample `c`

```
c <- a
c["B","C"] <- c["B","G"] <- c["C","B"] <- c["G","B"] <- -0.5
Heatmap(c, row_order = col_order, column_order = col_order, name = "c")
```

[image]

Variable B appears to no longer be part of a module with C,G.

Is anyone familiar with any formal approaches to this question that would allow me to conclude statistically what I am describing visually?